# How can i handle SYN / RST packets on nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I'm trying to build a simple server for a cyber research on the university. All I need is handling some requests which the server gets.

I've succeeded with GET methods, and I have to handle some more packets over Transport layer - SYN and RST.

Example: When a SYN packet arrives, the server has to send back SYN-ACK packet.

I started creating my server with http module, but I'm not sure that it could handle TCP packets, and I can't find any source for handling TCP packets.

Here is what I've started coding:

```
'use strict'
let http = require('http');
let fs = require('fs');
let path = require('path');

let PORT = 4500;
let address = "127.0.0.1";

require('dns').lookup(require('os').hostname(), function (err, add, fam) {
    address = add;
});

let server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log(`${req.method} request for ${req.url}`);
    if (req.url === '/') {
        fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err,data) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end(data);
        });
    } else if (req.url.match(/.jpg$/)) {
        let imgPath = path.join(__dirname, 'images', req.url);
        let imgStream = fs.createReadStream(imgPath);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
        imgStream.pipe(res);
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.end("404 File Not Found");
    }
});
server.listen(PORT, address);
console.log(`Server is running on ip ${address}, port ${PORT}.`);
```

I'm really new to JavaScript and Node.js, so any code suggestions will be welcomed! :)

Comment: A GET is an HTTP method, SYN/RST are TCP packets - they're not the same thing at all.  As TCP is a layer below HTTP, I'm not sure that an HTTP server will help you with this.

Comment: `<off-topic>` you may be new to Node and JS in general, but your code already looks way better than many other people here who don't yet know/understand what async or a callback are :) `</off-topic>`